# Correct Github Rebase work

Tags: git, github, rebase

I have no experience on Github, so I hope someone can help me to figure out the correct command sequence.

I'm on a Github repo that presents this situation:

```
------master     
     /
-- dev
     \
      --------extrabranch c11 --- extrabranch c12
```

That is, starting from the last commit on `dev`, I've merged it on `master`, then created a new branch `extrabranch` and added two commits to that branch. 
This situation is the same in the Github remote repository, and in local.

Now I would rebase `extrabranch` on `dev`.

Trying locally:

```
git rebase dev extrabranch
Current branch extrabranch is up to date.
git pull --rebase
Current branch extrabranch is up to date.
```

But the commits graph remains the same as the above.
Can someone explain to me why branch `dev` doesn't contain the commits `c11` and `c12` of rebased `extrabranch`?

Edit: my goal is to merge `extrabranch` into `dev`, and delete `extrabranch`, as cleanly as possible.

Comment: It doesn't sound like rebase is actually what you want to do here. `extrabranch` is *already* based off of dev. What do you _want_ the commit graph to look like?

Comment: Thanks: "already" is great keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at your graph. I have modified it to show a commit `c10`, which is where `master` and `dev` point. Your illustration doesn't show this, but by definition there must be a commit there.

```
-- c10 [master, dev]
     \
      --- c11 --- c12 [extrabranch]
```

The purpose of `git rebase` is to move commits, to be based on a specific point in the graph. You are telling git to rebase `extrabranch (c11 + c12)` onto `dev (c10)`. However, `extrabranch` is *already based on* `dev`, so there is nothing to do.

You say your goal is to merge `extrabranch` into `dev`, then delete `extrabranch` as cleanly as possible. The simplest approach is to merge it. Because there are no conflicts in the way, it will merge using fast-forward.

```
git checkout dev
git merge extrabranch
```

That will move the `dev` branch to where `c12` sits.

```
-- c10 [master]
     \
      --- c11 --- c12 [extrabranch, dev]
```

After that you should be able to delete `extrabranch` if you want to.

```
git branch -d extrabranch
```

```
-- c10 [master]
     \
      --- c11 --- c12 [dev]
```

This is assuming that there are no upstream commits on `dev`, which your post does not show. You can use `pull` or `fetch` to figure that out, though.

Comment: Works perfectly, and understood my conceptual error. If someone has my same problem, I add an extra: after deleting local extrabranch, to update on github I used additional command: `git branch -d origin/extrabranch` to remove the remote branch. Thanks @dan-lowe

Comment: Shouldn't the `c11` and `c12` commits come _after_ the `[dev]` part, in stead of replacing it? Now it seems that `c11` has already been merged into `master`...

Comment: @Peter Good point, my illustrations were confusing, actually they were wrong. I've redrawn them and tried to clean up the answer to be more clear.